# Fetch data from two tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables
Say Table-A and Table-B

```
Table-A

id | Article Name |date
1  | ABC          | 25/2/2011
2  | xyz          | 26/2/2011

Table-B

id | Comment      | Article-id
1  | good         | 1
2  | nice article | 2
3  | Apreciable   | 1
```

Output required is

```
Table-C

id | Article Name | date       | NumberOfComments
1  | ABC          | 25/2/2011  | 2
2  | xyz          | 26/2/2011  | 1
```

Please suggest !!!

Comment: A simple join? Try googling your question first

Comment: -1 Please read [ask]. This question shows a lack of research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do (untested, not at home):

```
SELECT Table-A.id, Table-A.article-name, Table-A.date, (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Table-B WHERE Article-id=Table-A.id) AS NumberOfComments FROM Table-A;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the query you are after.  I didn't test it to be sure there are no typos.  You are basically joining on `Table-B`, and then grouping the results back down to just those from `Table-A`, but counting how many "joins" were made.

```
SELECT [Table-A].id, [Article Name], date, COUNT(*) As NumberOfComments
FROM [Table-A]
LEFT JOIN [Table-B] On [Article-id] = [Table-A].id
GROUP BY [Table-A].id, [Article Name], date
```

Comment: @Julian's answer is good too.  If performance is a factor, be sure to test suitability of the provided answers.  Not all column types can be involved in a `GROUP BY` statement (e.g. ntext), @Julian's answer doesn't have this limitation like mine does.

Comment: Performance-wise, I think yours might be better. Subqueries are processed as a separate query, so it would probably require more work from the server.

Comment: Thanks a lot.but one thing ,please add table-a before "LEFT join". :-)

Comment: @Gourav, you're welcome.  Yeah, I caught that missing `FROM [Table-A]` just after I posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Table_A.*, count(*) as 'NoC' from Table_A 
inner join Table_B on Table_A.id = Table_B.idart 
group by Table_A.id
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to `GROUP BY` everything that is in the `SELECT`, unless it is a calculated field.  In your answer, you are just grouping by `id`, which means your query will probably produce a run-time error.